# Printing random numbers in a 2D array only once

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I'm trying to print a 2D array of random numbers from 1 to 15 only once. I've been able to print out the array but only sequentially.

```
int x =0;
public void Numberbox(){
            int[][] a2 = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,x}};

  String output = "";   // Accumulate text here (should be StringBuilder).
//... Print array in rectangular form using nested for loops.
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) 
{
for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) 
{
output += " " + a2[row][col];
}
output += "\n";
}
    System.out.print(output);


}
```

Comment: What do you mean "only sequentially"? Your code will print out 4 rows of 4 numbers each...what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @DNA I want it to print random numbers in each row so there is a possibility that it might repeat a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a collection, for example a list, and use the built-in shuffle function. For example:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(list); //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println(list); //[11, 5, 10, 9, 7, 0, 6, 1, 3, 14, 2, 4, 15, 13, 12, 8]

    int[][] a2 = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;  j< 4; j++) {
            a2[i][j] = list.get(i*4 + j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a2)); //[[11, 5, 10, 9], [7, 0, 6, 1], [3, 14, 2, 4], [15, 13, 12, 8]]
}
```

Comment: Can Collections.shuffle(list) only be used with ArrayList?

Comment: I have edited to get the result back into your 2D array. Any reasons why you want to use arrays and not collections?

Comment: I'm trying to make a puzzle program where the user movers the numbers around. I'm using a 4x4 matrix filled with 15 numbers and a blank. the blank will be controlled by a boolean operator. Will collections be able to do this?

Comment: That's a random arrangement of 16 numbers, which is not the same thing as 16 random numbers...

Comment: @DNA I think he does not want any duplicates

Comment: OK - A comment from the OP led me to believe that it _was_ the question - but a later comment implies the opposite, so I'm unsure now!

Comment: @DNA fair enough, it is admittedly a little confusing!

Comment: Collections.shuffle(list) can be used with any mutable list object. If you pass an immutable list, you will get exceptions, because shuffle works in-place.

Comment: Sorry if I got you guys confused. I just want to print a matrix of non-repeating numbers.

Comment: OK. But I have a problem with this line: List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); it suggest something for me to import but when I import them I get an error sign.

Comment: you need to add `import java.util.*;` before you class declaration

Comment: Yeah I did that. It say diamond operator is not supported in source 1.6. Is this a problem with my IDE (NetBeans).

Comment: I have amended. <> is only available from java 7+.

Comment: How can I get it to print in the form of a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `Collections.shuffle()` for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Random.nextInt()` within the inner loop to generate the random numbers:

```
public class RandomGrid
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int ROWS = 4;
        int COLS = 3;
        String output = ""; // Accumulate text here (should be StringBuilder).
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
            {
                output += " " + r.nextInt(16);
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
 12 9 10
 8 7 3
 8 10 11
 15 14 3
```

Comment: How can I stop a number from repeating?

Comment: You said in your comment above that you wanted random numbers, that might repeat! If you don't want repeating then the other answers using `shuffle()` are what you need.